# What can be the best place to put onCompletionListener in below java code?

Tags: java, android

I am understanding MediaPlayer in android. I want to show the toast message when the music is over.
What can be the best place to put onCompletionListener in below java code and why?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.musicplayer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void play(View v)
    {
        if(mediaPlayer==null)
        {
            mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.music);
        }

        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pause(View v)
    {
        if (mediaPlayer!=null)
            mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

}
```

Comment: why not simply after defining the `mediaPlayer` in `play()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is something you always want to do, I'd do it right after you create the player.  It just makes sense to set it up at the same time you create it.